# memcached and iptables

Tags: iptables, memcached

```
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);
```

Will port 11211 need to be open in `IPTables` for this to work, or is it bypassed considering it's `localhost`?

`sudo iptables -L -n -v` output

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1155K   95M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
8817K 1451M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
  183 10452 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:6685 
 574K   30M ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
  122  7232 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21 
 2649  154K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 8343K packets, 12G bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    6  2524 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp spt:20
```

Comment: Depends on what you already have in your iptables configuration.  On most distros everything is open by default.  If you post the output of 'iptables -L' on your system I can tell you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What everyone else has noted about default installs is fairly true, though most eg CentOS systems have come out of the box running a basic firewall for some time now.  **But** even a basic firewall will normally allow all connections from localhost to localhost, as is it extremely unwise to forbid these; the oddest things can start happening.  If there's a line near the top of your INPUT chain (or any chain to which INPUT delegates the bulk of its work) that says

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

or in `iptables -L -n -v` format,

```
  840 97979 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

(never mind the first two fields, they're packet and byte counts and yours would of course be different) then you're probably OK.  Another good test is to do

```
telnet localhost 11211
```

if you get

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
```

then you know your listener's running and the firewall's not blocking it.  Failing that, give us your `iptables -L -n -v` and your `netstat -an` outputs, as the others suggest, so we can take a look.

Comment: if I know that I can access MySQL via "localhost" then I should be fine.... right?

Comment: i don't see that that has much to do with the situation; mysql as a service normally runs on port 3306.  the telnet test is fairly definitive, and cheap to do; why would you not do it?

Comment: The telnet test was indeed met with "connection refused"..... `netstat-an` is a VERY long list of items...

Comment: ok, sorry, try "netstat -an|grep 11211".

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your install/distro.  The base install of pretty much everything should be open.  As dfranke pointed out you can list iptables entries with 'iptables -L'.  I can tell you that with a base install of Ubuntu, Debian and CentOS I've not had to do anything other than just install memcached to have it run and be open.